# when is the random loot generated?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does increased Magic Find work with chests?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67084/how-does-increased-magic-find-work-with-chests)

I was wondering how the loot is determined or if it even matters at all.  For example when I enter a map, is the loot of stuff already determined or only right when it drops? (Such as maybe a really great weapon is already in some random weapon rack, but I didn't open it.  Then I complain about not getting good weapons because I always happen to not open the good ones even though they are actually there).  This may be a dumb and irrelevant question since all the random events are independent?  Or something. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Loot is determined at the time it drops. There really isn't any other way to do it. What happens if you find a bunch of +magic find gear and equip it while in the dungeon? Conversely, what happens if you walk into a dungeon with all +MF gear on, thus generating a bunch of awesome gear and few legendaries, then change into your actual killing gear and clear it in a minute? It would be too easy to game the system if it was pre-determined.